# Facebook open graph Identical objects displaying different

Tags: facebook-graph-api, object, facebook-opengraph

I've created two custom action->object pairs in my app with identical structure (except each one has a own one custom property).

1) action: 'Rescue' -> object: 'Guardian'

Guardian have custom property 'stage' (string type)

2) action: 'Complete' -> object: 'Level'

Level have custom property 'level_type' (string type)

3) art (images) - both have 200x200 px

But they displays in different layout when i post them, and acts differently.

1) Complete a level story sample:

[image: complete a level]

The description for level not displayed, and not shown on level title hover. The image looks small then for guardian (but they both same size)

2) Rescue a Guardian sample. It looks like it should.

[image]

I want 'Complete a level' story looks same as 'Rescue a Guardian'
Please advance, thanks!

Comment: Oh, it seems the layout is different for different user accounts. Do not know why but i'am login under another account and now it looks good.

Comment: I've the same issue, but I want 'Rescue a guardian' story looks like 'complete a level'. Did you figure out how this happens?
Looks like when I look my own status, it looks wrong and when a friend looks at my status, it looks right.